# Versioning Google play

Tags: google-play, mobile-application, google-developers-console

I have been working to build an app and I ***deployed it only for testers***(internal testers).
yesterday I have done building the app and I want to publish it,
unfortunately, the version code is wrong the version code now is (3033 (2.8.0))
and I want to reset it can you guide me on how can I start from version
1.0.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contact support they don't allow me to reset the version code until the date of my answer
they reply:

**I checked into it and the Play Console doesn’t currently support resetting the version codes.**